# Have created a label with an index now want to add constrain

Tags: neo4j

I have created a label with and index and have many nodes within the label.  I now want to add the unique constraint but get the error:

Already indexed :BACM(name).

How can I add the uniqueness constraint to an existing label with nodes already existing?

Answer (score 3):

You have to drop the index and then add the constraint.

```
DROP INDEX ON :BACM(name)
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (bacm:BACM) ASSERT bacm.name IS UNIQUE
```

You'll need to do that in two separate queries.

The reason for this is that they're both Lucene indexes, just different types, and since Neo4j uses indexes without having to specify which index to use, it chokes if there's more than one of the same name.

EDIT: Should point out that the fact that you have many nodes already in place only matters if you have multiple nodes with conflicting names. Creating and dropping indexes won't hurt your nodes, the database will use an index when it's available, use Cypher otherwise, and will rebuild an index when told to. When you create your constraint, if you have two conflicting nodes, it will inform you and the new constraint will fail.

From my own test just now:

```
Unable to create CONSTRAINT ON ( omg:Omg ) ASSERT omg.foo IS UNIQUE:
Multiple nodes with label `Omg` have property `foo` = 'foo':
  node(2)
  node(4)
```